# hold some data at layer object

Tags: arcobjects, c#

Is there in arcobjects the ability to store some data at the layer in table of content sth. like

`ILayer.Tag` or an Interface which I can misuse for this?

Comment: Could you expand a little on what you're trying to do here?

Comment: While adding the layer to ArcMap by my tool I want to store some informations at the layerobject in order to access them later from another tool.

Comment: An alternative way is to have some global dictionary in an extension, I believe extensions can persist information after the application has closed, but I've never done that so don't know what the trappings are. In fact this is a good question, this information you want to store about the layers should it persist after the mxd has been closed?

Comment: No, if desired by customer I write them in a XML-File before closing. But if I have a global dictionary I have to watch the whole toc :-o but by thinking of it this would be the last option.